SQL Server Connection issues with Flask Web App
I have a python flask webapp and when the page is loading, connects to our SQL Server DB and saves certain tables as Panda data frames. This operation must happen as the page is loaded in. I am having issues connecting to my Server and database. Locally, everything runs completely fine, so I know this is a server-side issue. We have VNet integration set up for the web application and are experiencing weird and inconsistent errors.
The connection string that we are using is the following for SQLAlchemy:
    user = os.environ["USER_NAME"]
    password = os.environ["PASSWORD"]
    hostName = os.environ["HOSTNAME"]
    port = os.environ["SQLPORT"]
    db = os.environ["DATABASE"]

    # Establishing the database connection URI
    database_uri = f"mssql+pyodbc://{user}:{password}@{hostName}:{port}/{db}?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server"
    engine = create_engine(database_uri)

We learnt recently that the hostname was causing us issues. What I was using locally was not working in the web app (shortened name for the host). We attempted two possible solutions. One was the numerical address which did not work, and the other was the full name.
The full name for the host name worked when I restarted the web app. However, it is no longer working.
This morning, I received the same SQL Server connection error which is:
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
I then tried to switch the host name back to numerical address and it still was not working. When I switched it back to the full name and restarted the application it worked, and I was able to communicate for a couple messages before an error in my code (something related to state management which is not implemented yet as this app is in testing, and we only have one instance of it). However, when I reloaded the page again, I started to receive the same SQL connection errors again. I am puzzled as to why it worked twice when the host name variable was switched to the full name and the app was restarted and why in other scenarios it does not work at all. Currently the site and the host name environment variable are in the condition they were when the web app worked, only know the same error persists and I am not sure how to solve it. I can't check application logs either since the application fails to start due to the SQL Server Connection

Is your SQL Server an instance of the Azure SQL database service or something else? If something else, what is it?

@KonTheCat it is an instance of Azure SQL database service


sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

The above error indicates a login timeout issue,  occurs due to connection time with web app and sql sever  using sql and also if there are any mismatch with connection parameters. Also check with the firewall rules or any network issues. Try with the below code, it used VNET with Azure SQL Database and create Virtual Network for Azure App Services and Azure SQL  Database  which retrieves data successfully as shown in the output below.
connection_params = {
    'Driver': '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}',
    'Server': 'servername.database.windows.net',
    'Database': 'DatabaseName',
    'Uid': 'UidName',
    'Pwd': 'Pwd',
    'Encrypt': 'yes',
    'TrustServerCertificate': 'no',
    'Connection Timeout': '30'
}

def connect_to_sql_server():
    try:
        conn = pyodbc.connect(**connection_params)
        return conn
    except pyodbc.Error as e:
        print("Error connecting to Azure SQL Server:", e)
        return None

def fetch_data_as_dataframe(table_name):
    conn = connect_to_sql_server()
    if conn:
        try:
            query = f"SELECT * FROM {table_name};"
            df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
            return df
        except pyodbc.Error as e:
            print("Error fetching data from SQL Server:", e)
            return None
        finally:
            conn.close()
    else:
        return None

@app.route('/get_data/<table_name>')
def get_data(table_name):
    df = fetch_data_as_dataframe(table_name)
    if df is not None:
        return jsonify(df.to_dict(orient='records'))
    else:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Failed to fetch data from the specified table.'}), 500

@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def handle_exception(e):
    return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 500

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)


